# Strange issue with PowerShell Import-Csv not reading one column correctly

Tags: powershell, csv

I have created a csv file with fake user data.  This data is going to be used to populate a test Active Directory.  Well before I can get to that point I have to get Powershell to correctly read the contents of the CSV.

The issue can be repeated through the command line like this:

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv "C:\temp\randomNames.csv" -Header firstname, lastname, username, department, password, orgunit:

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.lastname
    $Department = $User.department
    $OU         = $User.orgunit

    Write-Host $Username
    Write-Host $Password
    Write-Host $Firstname
    Write-Host $Lastname
    Write-Host $Department
    Write-Host $OU
}
```

When the script runs it prints out everything fine except the OU variable.  I have no idea what I am missing here.

Here is an excerpt from the CSV file:

```
firstname,lastname,username,department,password,orgunit
Karry,Dwyer,KaDwyer,Marketing,happy1,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Johanna,Moon,JoMoon,Facilities,hentai,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Beatrice,Gropper,BeGropper,Messaging,12341234,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Rachelle,Houng,RaHoung,Research,jackson,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Leland,Smit,LeSmit,Executive,brother,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Marlin,Pyro,MaPyro,Engineering,123654,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Taisha,Goto,TaGoto,DBA,222222,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
Estelle,Holtzclaw,EsHoltzclaw,Engineering,ranger,"CN=Users,OU=bob,OU=com"
```

Comment: Your `Import-Csv` statement defines the last header as `orgunit:`, not `orgunit` (note the trailing colon). That's why `$User.orgunit` appears to be empty. But judging fro your CSV sample your data already comes with headers, so you don't need to manually specify them anyway. Just remove the `-Header` parameter from the `Import-Csv` statement.

Comment: You have a trailing colon on your first line:
    $ADUsers = Import-Csv "C:\temp\randomNames.csv" -Header firstname, lastname, username, department, password, orgunit:
Change this to:
    $ADUsers = Import-Csv "C:\temp\randomNames.csv" -Header firstname, lastname, username, department, password, orgunit